# Firefox css printing issue

Tags: html, css, firefox, printing

I have an html page that I want to print.  This page has a css formatting to it. When I go to print it out in Firefox, the print preview and the printed version has my data overlapping each other on the page breaks.  I am not currently controlling page breaks in my css.
Here is a screen shot of the print preview in firefox.  Notice the overlapping!

[image]

Not sure why this is happening or how to resolve. Has anyone seen this problem before?
Thanks for the help

Comment: I did forget to mention that the same css and html page prints great in google chrome.

Comment: "I am not currently controlling page breaks in my css". And since this seems like a viable solution, why haven't you tried this?

Comment: I have tried this but took it out since it did not change the issue.  For some reason , any data the spills over onto the next page looks like my screen shot above.  It seems that there is another underlying issue with firefox i am missing since every thing work well in chrome and IE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found the issue, and wanted to post it in case some one else runs across the same thing.
In my css I had

```
overflow: auto;
```

I totally forgot I even had this in there so changing it to

```
overflow: visible;
```

that fixed the printing issue.
Hope this will help someone!

Comment: The most radical way to do it is `@media print { * { overflow: visible !important; }}` - which I put into my stylesheet. However, it does not work in some cases... This is seriously broken in Gecko (or just Firefox?) - the WebKit- and Trident-based browsers handle it OK. Not to mention `page-break-inside: avoid;` for not cutting lines in half!